# Best ruby binding/gem for curl/libcurl

Tags: ruby, curl, rubygems, libcurl

I want to use the curl tool through ruby. So far I have invoked curl through the command line using `curl` and then parsing the data dumped from a file. However, I would like to use it from within my application. That would give me better control over the handling etc.

There are few gems out there http://curb.rubyforge.org/ and http://curl-multi.rubyforge.org/ However it's not clear which one is the best to use. I have the following criteria for decision

1. Stability and reliability of the library
2. Comprehensive support of underlying curl features. (I would be needing data posting, forging HTTP headers, redirects and multi-thread requests heavily.)

It would be great to get some feedback.

Thanks for your help.

-Pulkit

Comment: There is `Net::HTTP`, it can do all those things.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Looks like it's the default HTTP library that ships with ruby, but moving to a different library isn't an option. I have to use curl. Thanks.

Comment: Curl is for languages that don't have something awesome like mechanize. Php for example.

Comment: `Net::HTTP` is OK to use for basic things, but it's way too low-level. `Curb` is a good choice, it's de facto standard for accessing curl through ruby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly recommend [Typhoeus](http://rubydoc.info/gems/typhoeus/0.4.2/frames).  It relies on lib-curl, and allows for all sorts of parallel and async possibilities.  It offers ssl, stubbing, follows redirects, allows custom headers, true parallel requests for blazing speed, and generally has yet to let me down. Also, it is well maintained--at the moment, the last commit was 2 days ago!